# Laravel input type search cancel button submit form

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I want to submit the form when the user clicks the cancel button (x) in the search bar, how can i achieve this? because right now i have to delete the content in the searchbar and the click enter or the search button to clear the search in the table.[image]

Answer (score 0):

the solution is listen to the event when the user click in the x button and then submit the search form(id="search"):

```
<script type="module">
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener("search", function(event) {
    document.getElementById("search").submit();
});
</script>
```